# Pronunciation of 'finance' and 'financial' in the media

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, mass-media

This is just something I've noticed over the last few years in the English (UK) media and I wondered if there is some explanation for it.

It used to be that 'financial' and 'finance' were pronounced with an 'iy' sound (f*iy*nancial) - the I sound from 'sigh' or 'bye' for example. But it seems that all newsreaders and correspondents are currently under instructions to pronounce these with a hard I such as the I from 'kick'.

I find this particularly irksome with the word 'finance' for some reason!

Has anyone else noticed this? Is there a reason? Is it an Americanism?

Comment: The *"correct"* pronunciation, as given by the 1892 *Webster's International Dictionary* (American) and John Walker's 1828 *Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language* (British) has the short vowel of *"kick"*. So you're wrong about the "*way it used to be.*" I suspect that both pronunciations have been around  for the last 70 years. Of course, that doesn't explain why British newsreaders have suddenly settled on one pronunciation, if indeed they have and you're not just noticing it more because you started paying attention.

Comment: I almost think pronouncing it 'fiynancial' is more an example of Americanism.

Comment: There is example of pronounciation of [finance](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/finance) and [financial](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/financial). As you say, the right pronounciation is like *"bye"*

Comment: El -- pronunciations change constantly.

Comment: Interesting that you seem to equate 'Americanism' with 'irksome'!  It's their language as well.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Is the pronunciation with a short "i" associated with a stress on the second syllable of "finance"? That pronunciation is a lot easier for me to imagine than one with stress on the first syllable, like "FINN-ance". As an American, I'm used to pronouncing it with a stressed and diphthongal first syllable.

Comment: @sumelic: Yes, in the 19th century pronunciation, the second syllable was stressed and the vowel in the first syllable was the short i, /ɪ/.

Answer (score 2):

As a Brit I can only take the BBC as an example of correct pronunciation; they have departments for these things. Though the fin/fine thing does occur, it seems to me both versions of the word are generally pronounced "fiynancial".